# How to convert SQLDataReader to two list type when it returns two datatables?

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
public List<Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn> Get_UploadedDocumets(string RegNo)
{
    try
    {
        SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[]{
            new SqlParameter("@RegNo",(object)RegNo??DBNull.Value),
        };
        List<Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn> student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn = null;

        string lsError = string.Empty;
        using (SqlDataReader loSqlReader = SqlDBHelper.ExecuteParamerizedSelectCommand("usp_viewStudentDocuments", CommandType.StoredProcedure, parameters, out lsError))
        {
            //check if any record exist or not
            if (lsError.Length > 0)
                throw new Exception(lsError);
            if (loSqlReader != null)
            {
                //Lets go ahead and create the list of employees
                student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn = new List<Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn>();

                //Now lets populate the employee details into the list of employees
                while (loSqlReader.Read())
                {
                    student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn.Add(new Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn
                    {

                        //= Convert.ToString(loSqlReader["Document_Name"]),
                        ////  = Convert.ToString(loSqlReader["DocumentPath"])


                    });
                }
                loSqlReader.NextResult();

                while (loSqlReader.Read())
                {
                    student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn.Add(new Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn
                        {

                        });
                }
            }
        }

        return student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Here is my class where my list is present

```
public class Student_Uploaded_DocumentsEn
{
    public class DocumentListEn
    {
        public string Document { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
    }

    public List<DocumentListEn> Documentlist { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are the 2 datatables correlated? e.g. are there exactly the same number of rows in both, or is there a common key in both datasets?

Comment: Also, it would be nice to know what columns are those queries returning.